# MySQL merging rows with equivalent ID

Tags: mysql

I have an issue where a mistake resulted in a database table having both emails and GUIDs mixed in the ID column.

The table looks like this (simplified):

```
GUID | Value | Date
cf@a |   21  | 2016
mf@b |   42  | 2015
mf@b |   21  | 2016
1aXd |   3   | 2016
a7vf |   9   | 2015
```

Where for example user cf@a and user 1aXd are the same. The GUID - Email combinations are stored in another table. The emails are unique. Primary key is the ID(GUID) and the Date combined. My problem is, how do i update the table and merge the rows? the Value column of two merging rows should be summed.

So the example table assuming (cf@a -> 1aXd and mf@b -> 8bga and ui@q -> a7vf) would become:

```
GUID | Value | Date
1aXd |   24  | 2016   <-- merged, Value = 21+3
8bga |   42  | 2015   <-- converted to GUID
8bga |   21  | 2016   <-- converted to GUID
                      <-- one row removed (merged with the first  one)
a7vf |   9   | 2015   <-- untouched
```

Thank you for any help!

I could do this in C# but i would rather learn how to do it with the MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.Value + t2.Value
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 USING (`GUID`)
```

If you want update values, you need something like this:

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN t2 USING (`GUID`)
SET t1.Value = t1.Value + t2.Value
```

Removing merged rows:

```
DELETE t2 FROM t2
JOIN t1 USING (`GUID`)
```

**UPDATE**

If has only one table.

Merge:

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN (
    SELECT GUID, SUM(Value) as amount, COUNT(1) as cnt 
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY `GUID`
    HAVING cnt > 1
) t2 ON t2.GUID = t1.GUID
SET t1.Value = t2.amount;
```

Delete:

```
CREATE table t2 (
    GUID integer,
    Value integer,
    Date integer
);

INSERT INTO t2 (GUID, Value, Date)
SELECT GUID, Value, MAX(Date) FROM t1 GUID, Value;
```

Result will be in t2.

Comment: but this doesnt remove rows?

Comment: @maxx I updated answer with example of removing merged rows

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, wont that remove all the merged rows? I have just one table t1 inside which i want to merge rows.